# Best Method to present multiple View Controllers? Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

Currently my idea is as follows:
When an exisiting user logs into their account, they are taken from AuthVC -> MainVC. 
If the user needs to register, they go from AuthVC -> RegisterVC. Upon reigstering, they are taken to MainVC.
What I want is to present another VC over the top of MainVC upon the user registering.  So they go from ReigsterVC -> MainVC, but before they can interact with ManVC, the new VC will pop over the top to display a welcome message.
This extra VC will display a welcome message and explain the app etc.

The problem is that im not sure how I would actually go about doing this with a segue.. I was thinking something along the lines of 'If segue from Registervc = true, then present WelcomeMessageVC' or something along those lines...

The other idea i thought of was to put the welcome message on MainVC, but hidden unless segued from RegisterVC - although i would like to avoid this idea as i have already designed and created all my vc's and the WelcomeMessageVC is a separate VC. 
What would be the best/simplest way for this to work?

Another thought - Would it be possible to do this by using Firebase Auth, such as an if statement saying if user was just created, present WelcomeMessageVC, and if existing user present MainVC? 
Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: One way - maybe not the best, there are others - is to have keep the flow the way you have it - Auth >> Main or Auth >> Register >> Main - except pass a flag to Main that will have *it* present a Welcome VC on top of it's view. Once the user walks through Welcome VC, dismiss it and you're back to Main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your welcome view controller. On the Storyboard, create a segue and name it.

Store a boolean in user defaults to track if the person saw the welcome screen or not.

In your view controller viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear( animated )
    showWelcome()
}


func showWelcome() {
    var wasHereBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "wasHereBefore")

    // Do we have a value?
    if wasHereBefore == nil {
        wasHereBefore = false
    }
    if wasHereBefore == false {
        // Store the value so this only happens once
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "wasHereBefore")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "WelcomeSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.. Have just got round to connecting my UI up to code. Ive tested this and it works perfectly!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I use singleton for this problem. As you want MainVC always be loaded but depending if user is login or need to register. So start by creating a launcher class as singleton. and use that class to initialise your main view controller and before presenting check if user need to login etc and call that view. Once it is finished dismiss that view and your main view controller will be there already initialised. And even make changes depending on your requirement.

Look more into and I hope you will appreciate it.